Is there any interest in starting a journal club?
Over at CrossValidated, I've seen that they at least have had journal clubs in the past. I created this thread to check if there is any interest within the Cognitive Sciences community to do something similar.
In that case, I would gladly be in charge of setting up a first meeting.

sure, if you want to set it up!

I like the idea especially if you are keen to set it up.
It may encourage others interested in cognitive science / psychology to get involved with the site. In particular, I imagine that people interested in discussing journal articles are the kinds of people we want more involved with our site.
Naturally, a number of questions arise:

Is there sufficient interest?
What journal articles should be reviewed? How would you select an article that is of interest to enough people given the breadth of cognitive sciences, psychology, etc?
What format should the discussion take?
How could participation be sought from outside the typical user base of cogsci.se?

With regards to interest, I imagine that it would be worth an experiment at least once to see what kind of uptake there is.
With regards to format, just my opinion, but I think it would be great if the discussion interfaced with the site itself. One of the reasons that I participate on this site is that it leaves a legacy for others on the internet. I think it would be great if perhaps the discussion might generate some question-answer combinations on the main site.
In terms of seeking participation, perhaps this might be an exercise, we could more readily ask our colleagues to be involved with or ask users of other cognitive science / psychology sites whether they would like to participate.

For format, a regular chat event is a pretty good idea. Chat events can include a system message banner announcing the event (it's an option in the scheduling) which can draw in users on the front page that may not think about going into / know about the chatroom. :)

@Aarthi you can blame me for the fact that we still don't have a chat event... I do still think we should start one, but have just been far too busy with work to organize one yet. Hopefully things will settle down for me soon.
